# jQuery mobile dialog modal not opening on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open a modal popup dialog after loading ajax content in jQuery Mobile.

It works fine for the first time, it does not show any modal once it has shown for the first time.

following is the code :

```
 <div data-role="dialog" id="myDialog">
  <div data-role="header">
      <h1>My dialog heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" id="m_content">
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
      <h3>And my footer...</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript function

```
function cp() {
          $.get('@Url.Content("~/Mobile/StockReport/ItemWise")', function (data) {
              $("#m_content").html("").html(data);
              $.mobile.changePage('#myDialog');
          })

      }
```

Comment: do you load it via external link? do you get any errors? check if its still in DOM after opening it for the first time.

Comment: @Omar: i am not getting any errors. it seems that the div id="myDialog" is getting removed from page after closing.

Comment: if the dialog is loaded from an external file, it will be removed from DOM after navigating away.